# Avoid double concat in Ramda

Tags: javascript, concatenation, ramda.js

My question is simple. I started with [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/index.html) recently, and I like it, for it is pure functional. I have a little issue with *concat* function, as it only accepts two lists as arguments. So, if I need to concat three lists or more, I have to chain functions like this: `concat(list1, concat(list2, concat(list3, list4)))` (for a four lists concatenation). Is there any better way to do this, that I don't know? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use *reduce* function, but it returns another function instead of the list. Can you give me an example?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1QRXCGf

Comment: also note that there's not much advantage to doing it all inline like that, so in that case, the natives work just fine and are shorter: http://bit.ly/1QRYqLg  `[r,r2,r3,r4].reduce( (a,b)=>a.concat(b) )`

Comment: how about just using native code. `[].concat(list1, list2, list3, list4)`. just as pure and seems cleaner.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to concatenate a list of lists, you can reduce the list using `R.concat` with an empty list as the initial value.

```
const concatAll = R.reduce(R.concat, []);
concatAll([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]);
```

Or just pass the lists directly to `R.reduce`.

```
R.reduce(R.concat, [], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]);
```

If you want to create a new variadic function that takes each list as a separate argument, then you can wrap the function with `R.unapply`.

```
const concatAll_ = R.unapply(R.reduce(R.concat, []));
concatAll_([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]);
```

Ramda also has an `R.unnest` function, which when given a list of lists will concatenate them together.

```
R.unnest([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Ramda library, but you appears to be using this in node.js from the documentation I've read in the link you posted. In that case, you can use the `arguments` variable in a function in `node.js` to write your own `concat` function that takes n lists as input. The `arguments` variable is essentially an array of the arguments inputted into the function.

```
function myConcat () {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    concat(arguments[0], arguments[i]);
  }
  return arguments[0];
};
```

In this case however, you would probably have to call it like:

```
list1 = myConcat(list1, list2, list3, list4);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I was wishing a functional way to doing this. @dandavis got it right.

Comment: @MateusFelipe that's awesome. Sorry about that, I haven't used Ramda.js

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you are concatenating and your environment (ES2015 required), you could do:

```
 const newList = [...list1, ...list2, ...list3];
```

Otherwise, you are stuck with multiple calls to concat, though you could make it a little cleaner with compose:

```
 const newList = compose(concat(list1), concat(list2), concat(list4))(list3);
```

really though you want to map or better, reduce:

```
 const newList = reduce((acc, x) => concat(acc, x), [list3], [list4, list2, list1]);
```

or that inner reduce function could look like:

```
 (acc, x) => [...acc, ...x]
```

Comment: @ScottChrisopher reduce is cleaner, forgot to pointfree-ify my concat. However, concat isn't really a great example of ramda's composability as we could just call call concat natively with `[].concat(a, b, c)`, which s what the ES2015 code `[...a, ...b, ...c]` compiles to with babel

Answer (score 1):

Using `R.unnest` with `R.unapply` allows you to call your function as a variadic:

```js
const unnestAll = R.unapply(R.unnest)
unnestAll([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]) //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

A slight variation on [Scott Cristopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376699/999248)

See [Example in repl](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20unnestAll%20%3D%20R.unapply%28R.unnest%29%0AunnestAll%28%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C%204%5D%2C%20%5B5%2C%206%2C%207%5D%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%2C%206%2C%207%5D)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatten` method this way:

`R.flatten([list1, list2, list3, list4, ])`

Technically you pass a single array, which contains all your lists. Then you just flatten them all into a single array.

Do NOT use this method if some of your lists might contain list themselves - they'll be flattened as well.